# How to access my wordpress application using two URLs?

Tags: redirect

I have deployed a simple self managed Wordpress application on AWS. My setup looks like this.

```
AWS CloudFront -> AWS ALB -> EC2 servers [ wordpress runs] -> RDS Database
```

I have associated a base domain say https://example.com with my ALB and https://www.example.com with my Cloudfront distribution. The issue is that at any point in time, I am able to access the website using only either of the two URLs. And I have figured so far that the Wordpress automatically redirects me to the URL which i mention in the Site URL and the HOME URL settings in the admin dashboard.

As an example, if i updated my site URL and HOME settings to point to my CF URL, and then type my ALB domain name in the browser,  I automatically get redirected to the CF URL.
Upon inspecting, i see a 301 status code and then this as one of the response header.
X-Redirect-By : WordPress

The version of PHP/wordpress that i am hosting is PHP/7.2.34.

How can I stop this automatic redirection? How can I access my website using both the URLs?

Answer (score 0):

So this had been a constant issue for me but finally i got this working, thanks to this blog post.
http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/turn-off-wordpress-homepage-url-redirection/

It seems like adding this in the functions.php file for the enabled theme works. Pasting here for anyone who may be facing a similar issue.

```
 remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
```

I restarted the httpd and the php-fpm service, and now i am able to make it work as expected.